# Text overflowing in WordPress themes, Lines not breaking properly

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently I've noticed that most of the wordpress themes have this bug/issue with text overflowing.

Basically, the lines inside divs/sections aren't breaking where they should, they just go out of the box.

After reloading the page few times this is fixed tho. Any suggestion or idea how can this be avoided, so that it looks right at first page load?

On the image below you can see this happening with the twentyfifteen wordpress theme.

[image: Before and after page reload.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property for that particular div. like:

```
.div-class-name {word-wrap: break-word;}
```